# Extract a specific portion of video using MediaExtractor

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I am trying to use a portion of a pre-recorded video file for processing on Android. Currently I am working with MediaCodec library on Android. I am using MediaExtractor to extract the data from video file. The idea is to extract only required gata stream for processing. The code looks like:

```
    extractor = new MediaExtractor();

    File file = new File(mInputFile);

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    long len = file.length();
    long start = 200L;
    extractor.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD(),start,len);
    inputStream.close();
```

Logcat is:

> java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor.
>   at android.media.MediaExtractor.setDataSource(Native Method).

It works well if I set starting bytes to 0. What am I doing wrong ? Can we not extract portion of videos using mediaextractor ?

Comment: You probably want to use `MediaExtractor#seekTo()` instead. Also, remember that you need to start on a key frame boundary.

Comment: I tried that. Can you please tell how to find a key frame to seek to ?

Comment: The second argument to `seekTo()` is a "mode" flag. You can specify `SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC`, `SEEK_TO_NEXT_SYNC`, etc. If you're walking through the file, you can use `getSampleFlags()` to check for `SAMPLE_FLAG_SYNC`. "Key frame" and "sync frame" are equivalent in this context, though MediaCodec has started to deprecate the term "sync frame".

Comment: Thanks @fadden.. I did that with help of seekTo(). Only thing is, how to get the Metadata like bitrate, duration of the input video. I tried with MediaMetadataRetriever but I get  default values of the parameters when I try to access them.

Comment: As far as I know, it just pulls out whatever is present in the file, but I'm not especially familiar with that side of things.